# how to update query in CI

Tags: codeigniter

i have update query problem in codeigniter.

```
    $arrPartnerId = $partnerData['partner_id'];
            print_r($partnerData['partner_id']);

           if(is_array($arrPartnerId) > 0 ){
               foreach( $arrPartnerId as $partnerId){
                   $this->db->set('partner_id', $partnerId );
                   $this->db->where('promotion_id', $promotionData['promotion_id'] );
                   $this->db->update('partner_promotion_relation');
               }
           }
```

my data is $aaPartnerId=([0]=>4,[1]=>5) and i have one id then how to update in database.

Comment: `$promotionData['promotion_id']` is same for all set values then last value will affected in db

Comment: your table 'partner_promotion_relation' is updated twice in this case but rows are the same where 'promotion_id' = $promotionData['promotion_id'] so the same row is updated twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse a where and set condition, you should rather have this :

```
$this->db->set('promotion_id', $promotionData['promotion_id']);
$this->db->where('partner_id', $partnerId);
$this->db->update('partner_promotion_relation');
```

It's just a hypothesis, because in your case you keep update 2 times the same line in your table, which is not logical.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is like this,

```
$arrPartnerId = array(
                     0 => 4,
                     1 => 5
                     );
```

And

```
$promotionData['promotion_id'] = 123; //assumption
```

Then try this,

```
if(sizeof($arrPartnerId) > 0 )
      {
           foreach( $arrPartnerId as $partnerId)
           {
               $this->db->set('partner_id', $partnerId );
               $this->db->where('promotion_id', $promotionData['promotion_id'] );
               $this->db->update('partner_promotion_relation');
           }
      }
```

It will resolve the problem.